# I am flying Mexico-Frankfurt but I connect flights in Houston, do I need a special permit if I already have a visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, houston

I am flying Mexico-Frankfurt but I connect flights in Houston.

Do I need a special permit if I already have a visa?

I can't remember if I had to get one on my past travels.

Comment: What visa do you have for the US? Is it a visa that allows you multiple entries? Is it still valid?

Comment: What citizenship do you have?

Comment: What airline are you flying? What citizenship do you have? What visa do you already have to enter Germany?